Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'tapo.tapo'
I'm trying to import tapo library in a Python Lambda with the following code (which works locally with an equivalent main):
import asyncio
import os

from tapo import ApiClient


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    tapo_username = "username"
    tapo_password = "password"
    ip_address = "ip"

    client = ApiClient(tapo_username, tapo_password)

I've zipped this and manually uploaded on the lambda code. However, when I try to test it on my Lambda console I get:
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'tapo.tapo'",

Things I tried:

Just to clarify, the tapo dependency folder (installed through pip in the project) is at the same level as lambda_function.py
Using the request dependency with the same process, it works fine
Using a virtual env as described here
Using a lambda layer with only that tapo package

What am I doing wrong?

did you find a way to fix this issue?
